# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'circle')

Tags: reactjs, particles.js

I am using react-particles-js, I have just imported the Particles added the tag in the HTML

However, it is straight-up showing this error in the particle.js file of react-particles-js

> particles.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'circle')
> at Object. (particles.js:1:`enter code here`1)
> at r (particles.js:1:1)
> at Object. (particles.js:1:1)
> at r (particles.js:1:1)
> at Object.f (particles.js:1:1)
> at r (particles.js:1:1)
> at particles.js:1:1
> at Object../node_modules/react-particles-js/cjs/particles.js (particles.js:1:1)
> at Object.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
> at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)

```js
import "./scss/App.scss";
import ParticleBackground from "./components/ParticleBackground";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ParticleBackground />
      <CenterTitle />
    </div>
  );
}

function CenterTitle() {
  return (
    <div id="text_div center_all">
      <div className="center_all">
        <h1 className="custom-subTitle">Particle JS Integration</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Particles from "react-particles-js";
import ParticleConfig from "./particle-config";

export default function ParticleBackground() {
  return <Particles params={ParticleConfig}></Particles>;
}
```

Comment: you need to share your code, then only we will be able to help you?

Comment: I have added the code,

Answer (score 2):

This is not working because `react-particles-js` library has been deprecated in favor of `react-tsparticles`. You need to install `react tsparticles` and import according to its configuration.

**command to import tsparticles-** `npm install tsparticles`

**you can visit-** [react-tsparticles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles#ReactJS)

Comment: thanks a lot. I was stuck for hours

Comment: @ZiyaFatimaSayed if you wish, you can like and accept my answer, this will be helpful as well as for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

first of all uninstall the react-particle-js with npm uninstall react-particle-js. Then install npm install tsparticles
Then import it in your App.js file with import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
Open your console with right click inspect and in elements you will find  underneath